# javascript regular expressions with variables?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to execute a regular expression with a variable as the query.

```
//This works
$('body *').replaceText(/\b(Toronto)/gi, nameWrapper );
```

I need to have "Toronto" in a variable

```
var query = "Toronto";
$('body *').replaceText(/\b( --  query VARIABLE HERE --  )/gi, nameWrapper );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to build a regular expression from a string:

```
var query = "Toronto";
$('body *').replaceText(RegExp("\\b(" + query + ")", "gi"), nameWrapper);
```

And to quote your string properly, you can use this:

```
RegExp.quote = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/(?=[\\^$*+?.()|{}[\]])/g, "\\");
}
```

Then just use `RegExp.quote(query)` instead of `query` when building the regular expression:

```
var query = "Toronto";
$('body *').replaceText(RegExp("\\b(" + RegExp.quote(query) + ")", "gi"), nameWrapper);
```

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile with the regex cleaner.

Comment: @BahaiResearch.com: Unfortunately JavaScript doesn’t provide such a method.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
var query = 'Toronto';
var regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + query + ')', 'gi');
$('body *').replaceText(regex, nameWrapper);
```